# Postgres - search in json array of elements

Tags: json, postgresql

My table:

> id | name | open_days

Column open_days is a json column with following structure:

```
{
daysOfWeek: ['mon','tue','sat']
months: ['may','november']
}
```

I would like to find rows where daysOfWeek contain searching element. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM places WHERE :day=ANY(open_days->'daysOfWeek')
```

But above query is not correct.
Pleas help how to search is json array.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `open_days` is a `jsonb` column (which it should be), then you can use the contains operator `?`:

```
select *
from places
where open_days -> 'daysOfWeek' ? :day
```

If it's a `json` column, you need to cast it `open_days::jsonb -> ...`

---

If you want to search for values that contain multiple weekdays, you can use the `?&` operator:

```
select *
from places
where open_days -> 'daysOfWeek' ?& array['mon','tue']
```

the above would return all rows that contain `mon` **and** `tue`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `json_array_elements()`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM places
       WHERE :day = ANY (SELECT json_array_elements(open_days->'daysOfWeek')#>>'{}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do this is with the containment operator.

```
select * from places where open_days @> '{"daysOfWeek":["mon"]}'
```

An advantage over using `-> ... ?` is that containment can use the default JSONB index, while the other would require a specialized index.